# Bootstrap Modal Log-In Form Disappears Immediately?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm making a modal form that allows users to log in. As soon as I click on "Log In" the modal form appears and disappears.

Here is the button that calls the modal form. It is part of my navigation bar:

```
<li><a href=#myModal data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
```

Modal Body:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tableindex='-1'>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Log-in</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" type="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" type="password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Log-in</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me on [jsBin](https://jsbin.com/titiseyabu/2/edit?html,output).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <li><a href=#myModal data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tableindex='-1'>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Log-in</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" type="email">
          </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" type="password">
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Log-in</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks, the stuff I had in the <head> was a mess and I wasn't sure which scripts and links to keep on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may be loading the JavaScript for Bootstrap Modal twice. Are you possibly loading **bootstrap.js** as well as **bootstrap-modal.js**? Or both **bootstrap.js** and **bootstrap.min.js**?